# Connecting sublime_text3 editor with postgresql

Tags: 12.10, connection, postgresql

I am new in sublime_text3. I want to connect my sublime_text editor with my system PostgreSQL in ubuntu12.10.

I have tried few plugins but its not working. Any one have any idea how to do that?

Comment: User has reposted this from http://stackoverflow.com/q/21375254/398670